# How to use a local font in Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a font in a `fonts/` directory. How do I load this into the game, then use it on a text object in my game? I haven't been able to find anything on using fonts in Phaser 3.

Comment: It's a bit hidden but there is an example folder for fonts in the phaser docs: http://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=game%20objects/text/static/

Answer (score 31):

First use css to load your font(@fontface):

```
<style media='screen' type='text/css'>
      @font-face {
        font-family: font1;
        src: url('media/yourfont.ttf');
        font-weight:400;
        font-weight:normal;
      }
</style>
```

And then use a `div` to load your font:

```
<div style="font-family:font1; position:absolute; left:-1000px; visibility:hidden;">.</div>
```

Now you can put it in add it in your game:

```
this.add.text(190, 136, 'text', {
    fontFamily: 'font1',
});
```

Comment: It works! In the beginning I didn't put the point in the middle of the div and it didn't work.

Comment: This doesn't work if you are using Parcel or Webpack to bundle up your assets. In that case, you have to use JS import as above to fetch the correct file name.

Answer (score 11):

### Pure JS Solution:

Here's a small function I made, which only requires the font name and url:

```js
function loadFont(name, url) {
    var newFont = new FontFace(name, `url(${url})`);
    newFont.load().then(function (loaded) {
        document.fonts.add(loaded);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return error;
    });
}
```

And use it like:

```js
loadFont("mixolydian", "assets/fonts/mixolydian.ttf");
```

That's it! You can now use your custom font in Phaser. All you have to do is change the `fontFamily` value to your new font name (i.e. mixolydian).

Comment: When using TypeScript this won't compile - it doesn't recognize neither `FontFace` not `documents.fonts`

Comment: Perfect solutions , thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Phaser 3 there is a good [official example for Custom Webfont](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/text/custom-webfont)

This comes down to:

```
preload () {
    this.load.script('webfont', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js');
}

create () {
    WebFont.load({
        custom: {
            families: [ 'troika' ]
        },
        active: function () {
            this.add.text(32, 32, 'The face of the\nmoon was in\nshadow.', { fontFamily: 'troika', fontSize: 80, color: '#ff0000' }).setShadow(2, 2, '#333333', 2, false, true);
        }
    });
}
```