# How to use a external font using bitmaptext or text in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a font in a fonts/ directory. How do I load this into the game, then use it on a text object in my game? I haven't been able to find anything on using fonts in Phaser 3.

I tried out multiple methods and property from the

https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=&q=

https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs

this both link for the phaser3 but not able to set the width of the perticular text

i also try to apply font using css but it also not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just after answering your question, I noticed a [very similar question with similar text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217147), from another user; the given answer is ok. What happened? If the given answers do not work for you, please be really more precise in your question, so that people can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a local font in Phaser 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217147/how-to-use-a-local-font-in-phaser-3)

Answer (score 3):

First, load the font from your css in the normal way, something like this (if the url is relative like below, it must be relative to the css file):

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Indie Flower";
    src: url(../fonts/IndieFlower.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

Then use the font family in your text objet style:

```js
function create() {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'My text', {
        fontFamily: 'Indie Flower',
        fontSize: '2.5em'
    });
}
```

See [the Phaser.js docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Text.TextStyle.html) to see all the available properties.

You may have issues about font loading: I mean the font may not display on load, and you may have to wait for the load then change your text in order to display the font; I'm not an expert about it and there are many different solutions for this. For my part when I tested my answer, I just added this line at the beginning of the html body, and it fixed the issue:

```html
<span style="font-family:'Indie Flower'"></span>
```

Comment: Do you know if this trick works with all browsers? Excellent trick.